# Github commit history gap due to email typo - any solutions?

Tags: github

Is there a way to add commits for the previous day on Github?

I'm really keen on being able to see my progress; at some point I was messing around and changed the config email.

So now my profile has a huge gap in the commit history over the course of an entire week, is there any way to fix this?

I already re-configured the email and found the typo